# Anime with a scene involving summoning a eldritch creature

Tags: story-identification, anime

I am trying to find the title of an anime from a scene featured in an old Youtube (Dailymotion?) video (which, alas, has probably been removed...).
A group of adventurers (a boy, a girl and I think a wizard) is trying to summon some eldritch creature from a bubbly/boiling pool (possibly a cauldron?) via some sort of ritual (possibly in a dungeon?). The ritual involves mock-sacrificing the girl, or using her as bait (basically they are going fishing), or something along those lines. At the end of the day, they manage to summon the monster, the girl ends up s safely in the boy's arms and... well, the video stopped there, with the characters staring at the abomination they just lured out of this boiling/bubbly pool/cauldron. I have no idea how the episode ends!

After a bit of research, I have found some anime that are similar in terms of release date (based on animations) and 'mood':

- Slayers
- Outlanders
- Maze
- El Hazard
- Fushigi Yugi
- Tenchi Muyo
- Mahou Senshi Louie

However none of them seem to be a match...

Any idea on what could it be?